# run mips code in mars4_5

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I have a program to find maximum prime number in a given array coded in C:
https://pastebin.com/1HrerxsH

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, N = 1000, l = 0;
    int a[N], primeArr[l];

    printf("Array of numbers: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand();
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Array of prime numbers: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int k, numDivisor = 0;
        for (k = 1; k <= a[i]; k++)
            if (a[i] % k == 0)
                numDivisor++;
        if (numDivisor == 2)
        {
            primeArr[l] = a[i];
            printf("%d ", primeArr[l]);
            l++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    if(l > 0)
    {
        printf("Max prime numbers: \n");
        int max = primeArr[0];
        for (i = 1; i < l; i++)
        {
            if (primeArr[i] >= max)
                max = primeArr[i];
        }
        printf("%d", max);
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

After compile it into MIPS assembly by MIPS CROSS COMPILER, I obtain the code in .s file extension:
https://pastebin.com/NTMHY9Jw

```
    .file   1 "test3.c"
    .rdata
    .align  2
    $LC0:
    .ascii  "Array of numbers: \n\000"
    .align  2
$LC1:
    .ascii  "%d \000"
    .align  2
$LC2:
    .ascii  "\n\n\000"
    .align  2
$LC3:
    .ascii  "Array of prime numbers: \n\000"
    .align  2
$LC4:
    .ascii  "Max prime numbers: \n\000"
    .align  2
$LC5:
    .ascii  "%d\000"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,72,$31      # vars= 40, regs= 3/0, args= 16, gp= 0
    .mask   0xc0010000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-72
    sw  $31,64($sp)
    sw  $fp,60($sp)
    sw  $16,56($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $sp,40($fp)
    li  $2,1000         # 0x3e8
    sw  $2,20($fp)
    sw  $0,24($fp)
    lw  $2,20($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    addiu   $2,$2,7
    addiu   $2,$2,7
    srl $2,$2,3
    sll $2,$2,3
    subu    $sp,$sp,$2
    addiu   $2,$sp,16
    addiu   $2,$2,7
    srl $2,$2,3
    sll $2,$2,3
    sw  $2,44($fp)
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    addiu   $2,$2,7
    addiu   $2,$2,7
    srl $2,$2,3
    sll $2,$2,3
    subu    $sp,$sp,$2
    addiu   $2,$sp,16
    addiu   $2,$2,7
    srl $2,$2,3
    sll $2,$2,3
    sw  $2,48($fp)
    la  $4,$LC0
    jal printf
    sw  $0,16($fp)
$L2:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    lw  $3,20($fp)
    slt $2,$2,$3
    beq $2,$0,$L3
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $3,44($fp)
    addu    $16,$2,$3
    jal rand
    sw  $2,0($16)
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $4,44($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$4
    la  $4,$LC1
    lw  $5,0($2)
    jal printf
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    j   $L2
$L3:
    la  $4,$LC2
    jal printf
    la  $4,$LC3
    jal printf
    sw  $0,16($fp)
$L5:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    lw  $3,20($fp)
    slt $2,$2,$3
    beq $2,$0,$L6
    sw  $0,32($fp)
    li  $2,1            # 0x1
    sw  $2,28($fp)
$L8:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $3,44($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$3
    lw  $3,0($2)
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    slt $2,$3,$2
    bne $2,$0,$L9
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $4,44($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$4
    lw  $3,0($2)
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    div $0,$3,$2
    bne $2,$0,1f
    break   7
1:
    mfhi    $2
    bne $2,$0,$L10
    lw  $2,32($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,32($fp)
$L10:
    lw  $2,28($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,28($fp)
    j   $L8
$L9:
    lw  $3,32($fp)
    li  $2,2            # 0x2
    bne $3,$2,$L7
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $4,48($fp)
    addu    $3,$2,$4
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $4,44($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$4
    lw  $2,0($2)
    sw  $2,0($3)
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $3,48($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$3
    la  $4,$LC1
    lw  $5,0($2)
    jal printf
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,24($fp)
$L7:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    j   $L5
$L6:
    la  $4,$LC2
    jal printf
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    blez    $2,$L13
    la  $4,$LC4
    jal printf
    lw  $4,48($fp)
    lw  $2,0($4)
    sw  $2,32($fp)
    li  $2,1            # 0x1
    sw  $2,16($fp)
$L14:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    lw  $3,24($fp)
    slt $2,$2,$3
    beq $2,$0,$L15
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $3,48($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$3
    lw  $3,0($2)
    lw  $2,32($fp)
    slt $2,$3,$2
    bne $2,$0,$L16
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    sll $2,$2,2
    lw  $4,48($fp)
    addu    $2,$2,$4
    lw  $2,0($2)
    sw  $2,32($fp)
$L16:
    lw  $2,16($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,1
    sw  $2,16($fp)
    j   $L14
$L15:
    la  $4,$LC5
    lw  $5,32($fp)
    jal printf
    lw  $sp,40($fp)
    sw  $0,36($fp)
    j   $L1
$L13:
    lw  $sp,40($fp)
    li  $2,-1           # 0xffffffffffffffff
    sw  $2,36($fp)
$L1:
    lw  $2,36($fp)
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $31,64($sp)
    lw  $fp,60($sp)
    lw  $16,56($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,72
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

But when I run the .s file in MARS4_5, it appears these errors:
".align" directive cannot appear in text segment

".ascii" directive cannot appear in text segment

"1" is not a recognized operator

"1f": operand is of incorrect type

"$31": operand is of incorrect type

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

MARS doesn't recognize the rdata segment; change it to just data. For good measure, remove all the .align directives, since they were inserted the compiler to improve performance but aren't really necessary if you're just running this in MARS. Finally, to get rid of the "operand is of incorrect type", you'll need to figure out where the computer actually intended for those labels to point and patch it up manually.